# Redirect a wildcard subdomain with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, wildcard

I have updated my website and now i have a new URL structure. My old structure was like: subdomain.domain.com. My new structure is like: www.domain.com/folder/subdomain

I already added a subdomain wildcard to my dns (*.domain.com) and was hoping for a htaccess rule to redirect my old urls to my new urls.

(how) can this be done?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+).domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ /folder/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Try putting this code in the `htaccess` file.